# Rendering web page as thumbnail

Tags: javascript, canvas, firefox-addon

I asked this question earlier, since I am a little new to Firefox extension development, the canvas thing for Firefox went a little over my head. Apologies for reposting this again.

1. with the first answer there was this code snippet:

```
var path = this.getPref("path","string");
```

what are the path and string? yes I did look up for getPref in MDC but it made a little sense. Does Path refer to the URL of the web page that I am rendering(e.g: http://en.wikipedia.org/) and what does "String" refer to? I know I might sound a little stupid but it seriously went over my head.

2. After the images of the web pages are rendered, where are they saved? How do i know if the image has been rendered?
3. With the draw window if I have framed the browser will it be **window.frames[0]** in place of **content**

```
context.drawWindow(content,0,0,canvas.height,canvas.width,"rgb(255,255,255)");
```

Answer (score 0):

getPref is not a standard javascript function but perhaps it does something like this. Would be great if you post that "code snippet".

```
// getPref
// Syntax: "?width=80&height=25".getPref("width"); // Returns 80
String.prototype.getPref = function(s, splitter) {
  return this.split(s+"=")[1].split((splitter||"7"))[0];
};
```

> After the images of the web pages are
>   rendered, where are they saved?

Browser's cache?

> How do i know if the image has been rendered?

look at `img.complete`

> With the draw window if i have framed
>   the browser will it be
>   window.frames[0] in place of content
>   context.drawWindow(
>   content,0,0,canvas.height,canvas.width,"rgb(255,255,255)");

what?

Comment: if i ahve framed my browser with an extension, is there someway i can capture the screenshot of the webpage in one particular frame? Did i make sense?

Comment: And when i scale the image captured, is there someway i can retain the quality of the image, because when i scale the image to a thumbnail size it becomes bit blury?

Comment: 1) you can capture any website, just use the url of the iframe
2) use a sharpen filter